# How to separate an Array in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter

I am using codeIgniter. I have created a model to fetch all records from a table. In controller i am sending data to a view in an Array, and in view i am printing all the data in `form fields`.

The problem i am facing is that i am unable to  understand how to associate data of `images` (Which is in another array) into 3 different form fields.

This is what i am getting when i echo images

```
    foreach ($results as $fetch_data)
    {
      echo $image1=$fetch_data->images;  
    }
```

Output:-

```
/images/img22.jpg/images/img23.jpg/images/img24.jpg/images/img25.jpg
```

Its printing all the array in a single line, i am unable to understand how to departs them.
Kindly guide me. Given below is my complete code.

Model

```
public function fill_form($id) 
{
 $this->db->select("products.product_id , products.price, products.name,
                    products.color, products.size, product_images.product_id,
                    product_images.images, product_images.image_id ");
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('product_images', 
                    'products.product_id = product_images.product_id');
    $this->db->where('products.product_id',$id);
    $query= $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
  public function fill_controller()
  {
        $product_id=$this->uri->segment(3);        
        $data['results']=$this->products_model->fill_form($product_id);
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('update_product',$data);    
        $this->load->view('footer');

  }
```

VIEW

```
        <?php
        foreach ($results as $fetch_data)
        {
            $product_id=    $fetch_data->product_id;
            $product_name=  $fetch_data->name;
            $price=         $fetch_data->price;
            $color=         $fetch_data->color;
            $size=          $fetch_data->size;
            echo $image1=       $fetch_data->images;           
        }

HTML
        Front Image:    
                        <input type="file" name="userfile_1">           
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url().$image1;  ?>" width="50" height="50">
                        <br>



        Right Sleeves Images:
                        <input type="file" name="userfile_2">         <br>


        Left Sleeves Images
                        <input type="file" name="userfile_3">         <br>
```

Array Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 76
            [price] => 6000
            [name] => MyName
            [color] => Blue
            [size] => Small/Medi
            [images] => /images/img22.jpg
            [image_id] => 21
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 76
            [price] => 6000
            [name] => MyName
            [color] => Blue
            [size] => Small/Medi
            [images] => /images/img23.jpg
            [image_id] => 22
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 76
            [price] => 6000
            [name] => MyName
            [color] => Blue
            [size] => Small/Medi
            [images] => /images/img24.jpg
            [image_id] => 23
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 76
            [price] => 6000
            [name] => MyName
            [color] => Blue
            [size] => Small/Medi
            [images] => /images/img25.jpg
            [image_id] => 24
        )

)
```

Comment: show your result array do `echo "<pre>";print_r($data['results']);`

Comment: i don't think you mean `echo $image1=$fetch_data->images;` remove the `echo` from this line? and show the output of `var_dump($image1);`

Comment: I dont see any problem in his code. Just remove the echo before $image1 and see what happens

Comment: i have updated my question..Kindly check it

Comment: So what is your problem? Can you show some sample output as what you want and what are you getting?

Comment: I am unable to get the data of all images in my form. In my form it only give me the path of last url. I have tried to use an array but it also only giving me last path, and not storing all 3 paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a combination of GROUP_CONCAT in your query with explode in PHP.

```
 $this->db->select("products.product_id , products.price, products.name,
    products.color, products.size, GROUP_CONCAT(product_images.images) AS images,
    GROUP_CONCAT(product_images.image_id) AS  image_id");
```

In view

```
foreach ($results as $fetch_data){
           $product_id    = $fetch_data->product_id;
            $product_name = $fetch_data->name;
            $price  =       $fetch_data->price;
            $color  =       $fetch_data->color;
            $size   =       $fetch_data->size;
            $image  =       $fetch_data->images;
            $images = explode(",",$image);
}
```

HTML

```
 Front Image: <input type="file" name="userfile_1">    
    <?php if(!empty($images[2])){ ?>       
          <img src="<?php echo base_url().$images[0];  ?>" width="50" height="50">
    <?php } ?>
    <br>

    Right Sleeves Images: <input type="file" name="userfile_2">    
    <?php if(!empty($images[2])){ ?>     
        <img src="<?php echo base_url().$images[1];  ?>" width="50" height="50">
    <?php } ?>
    <br>

    Left Sleeves Images : <input type="file" name="userfile_3">         
    <?php if(!empty($images[2])){ ?>
       <img src="<?php echo base_url().$images[2];  ?>" width="50" height="50">
    <?php } ?>
    <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using GROUP CONCAT. Then you can use explode in your loop to separate data

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

I think its a access modifier issue your $image1 variable scope is only still in foreach loop you could not get it outside from the loop

to access it end you loop on the page end and print it like that.. also print the html in foreach loop

In Your view

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $fetch_data)
{
    $product_id=    $fetch_data->product_id;
    $product_name=  $fetch_data->name;
    $price=         $fetch_data->price;
    $color=         $fetch_data->color;
    $size=          $fetch_data->size;
    $image1 =       $fetch_data->images;           
?>
Front Image:    
                <input type="file" name="userfile_1">           
                <img src="<?php echo base_url().$image1;  ?>" width="50" height="50">
                <br>



Right Sleeves Images:
                <input type="file" name="userfile_2">         <br>


Left Sleeves Images
                <input type="file" name="userfile_3">         <br>



<?php
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: you missed the closing of `foreach` loop and the `echo` in front of `$image=` is not required (can mess up html)